# Does this weakening of split monomorphism have a name?

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, terminology, definition

Throughout, let the morphism $A \overset{f}{\to} B$ be given. We say that *"the extension problem for $f$ along $A \overset{t}{\to} T$ has a solution"* if there exists a morphism $B \overset{g}{\to} T$ such that $g \circ f = t$.

(We are ***not*** requiring $t$ to be a monomorphism, as is commonly done [according to nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/extension).)

One can show that if $f$ is a **split** monomorphism, then for *all* objects $T$ in the category, $f$ solves the extension problem for all $A \overset{t}{\to} T$. The converse is also true, since a retraction is just a solution to the extension problem for $f$ along $A \overset{id_A}{\to}A$.

> **Question:** Is there a name for a morphism $f$ such that, *for a given object $T$* (i.e. not necessarily *all* objects $T$) in the category, the extension problem for $f$ along every $A \overset{t}{\to} T$ has a solution?

I don't think this is the same thing as $f$ "[having the left lifting property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lifting_property) with respect to $1_T$", since it seems like every morphism (trivially) "has the left lifting property with respect to $1_T$".

Also this has to be *strictly* stronger than having the left cancellative property for morphisms $T \to A$, since if it weren't then every monomorphism would be a split monomorphism.

[Lawvere and Schanuel](https://books.google.com/books?id=6G0gAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA52&lpg=PA52&dq=%22injective%20for%20maps%22&source=bl&ots=hVftkvOke3&sig=6W3h5lue3SgYjmKTaaKOH7sD16w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiv2YP5lpfYAhVDkeAKHYLiC7sQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22injective%20for%20maps%22&f=false) call the analogous property for lifts (instead of extensions) "surjective for maps from $A$", but what they call "injective for maps from T" corresponds to the strictly weaker property mentioned above. I.e. a morphism is a monomorphism (not necessarily split) if and only if it is "injective for maps from $T$" for all $T$, but a morphism is "surjective for maps from $T$" for all $T$ if and only if it is a **split** epimorphism.

So there seems to be no name for the "single $T$" property for either arbitrary epimorphisms, or for *split* monomorphisms -- my question is above is about the terminology for split monomorphisms.

Comment: I imagine the usual term is "$f^* : \hom(B,T) \to \hom(A,T)$ is surjective".

Comment: You could say $f$ is projective with respect to $T$.

Comment: @KevinCarlson Thank you for this suggestion. Why does it work to say that $f$ is projective? (What is a projective morphism?) Is there an explanation that doesn't use schemes? https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01W7 (I haven't learned much about schemes yet.)

Comment: @Hurkyl That is definitely the type of clear/great description I am looking for. ($f^*$ means the map formed by pre-composing with $f$ right? Please correct me if this explanation attempt is wrong: Because of the nature of the extension problem, we are looking for $g$ such that $g \circ f = t$. Thus $f^* : g \mapsto g \circ f$ is surjective because every determination problem has a solution, i.e. given any $t \in \hom(A,T)$, there exists a $g \in hom(B,T)$ such that $f^*(g) = g \circ f = t$.) So we can just consider $f^*$ to be the image of $f$ under the contravariant Hom functor $Hom(-,T)$?

Comment: Then the analogous property for (split) epimorphisms is probably called "being surjective for maps from $A$" by Lawvere and Schanuel since then we're saying that the image of $B \overset{g}{\to} T$ under the ***co***variant Hom functor $Hom(A, -)$, $Hom(A,g): Hom(A,B) \to Hom(A,T)$, $Hom(A,g): f \mapsto g \circ f$ (post-composition) is surjective, since for every $t \in Hom(A,T)$, the lift problem along $g$ has a solution, so that there is an $f \in Hom(A,B)$ so that $Hom(A,g)(f)=g \circ f = t$. (In the original post I failed to account for how they re-labeled the objects in the diagram.)

Comment: @Chill2Macht: Yes; that is a good elaboration of my comment.